# Spring AOP exception handler - execute only first aspect in ordering

Tags: spring, exception, aop, exceptionhandler

**UPD** I've updated code for Aspects to throw exception further

I have SpringBoot application, service class and I need to implement Exception Handler for my service (not MVC). The task is to log error and throw it further to the client.

I decided to use Aspect with `@AfterThrowing` advice. I'm gonna catch few exceptions (that extend `RuntimeException`) at `AspectOne` aspect. And for other cases I need to catch exceptions (that extend RuntimeException) at `AspectTwo` aspect.

So I did the following code:

```java
public class MyOwnException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

```java
@Aspect
@Order(0)
@Component
public class AspectOne {

@Pointcut("execution(* com.test.MyService.*(..))")
public void logException() {}

@AfterThrowing(pointcut="logException()", throwing="ex")
public void logException(MyOwnException ex) {
  System.out.println("MyOwnException has been thrown: " + ex.getMessage());
  throw ex;
}

}
```

```java
@Aspect
@Order(1)
@Component
public class AspectTwo {

@Pointcut("execution(* com.test.MyService.*(..))")
public void logException() {}

@AfterThrowing(pointcut="logException()", throwing="ex")
public void logException(RuntimeException ex) {
  System.out.println("Some unknown exception has been thrown: " + ex);
  throw ex;
}

}
```

The problem is that `AspectTwo` is executed in both cases for `MyOwnException` and other ancestors of `RuntimeException`. How can I limit `AspectTwo` to be executed only when `AspectOne` haven't caught the exception?

Seems like `@Order` annotation works not as I expected.

Comment: The order works exactly as to be expected. It first executes AspectOne then AspectTwo. It will **not** limit the execution because something already ran. Implement logic in aspect two to ignore errors handled by other aspects.

Comment: Do you mean to ignore it by using instanceof in the AspectTwo? I expected to use something more generic like some feature that says this exception has been come from the first aspect". Otherwise every new exception I should add to both aspects

Comment: Or write a single aspect that handles well know exception in a way and other in a different way also you don't need to retrhow the exception AFAIK, it will propagate anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How about a little hack to indicate an exception is already handled/adviced ?

Also note that , the order of execution to be `AspectOne` before `AspectTwo` here , the `Order` should be specified as 1 for `AspectOne` and 0 for `AspectTwo`.

From the reference documentation section : [Advice Ordering](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering)

> **What happens when multiple pieces of advice all want to run at the
> same join point?** Spring AOP follows the same precedence rules as
> AspectJ to determine the order of advice execution. The highest
> precedence advice runs first "on the way in" (so, given two pieces of
> before advice, the one with highest precedence runs first). "On the
> way out" from a join point, the highest precedence advice runs last
> (so, given two pieces of after advice, the one with the highest
> precedence will run second).

Following code leverages the [Throwable.addSuppressed()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed(java.lang.Throwable)) method to indicate an exception object is already handled/adviced.

--

Add an `Exception` class to be used as an indicator.

```
public class AlreadyAdvicedIndicator extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public AlreadyAdvicedIndicator(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

`AspectOne` with modified `Order` and logic to add a suppressed exception.

```
@Component
@Aspect
@Order(1)
public class AspectOne {

    public static final String ALREADY_ADVICED_MSG="Adviced with AspectOne";
    
    private static final AlreadyAdvicedIndicator alreadyAdviced = new AlreadyAdvicedIndicator(ALREADY_ADVICED_MSG);

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.test.MyService.*(..))")
    public void logException() {}

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut="logException()", throwing="ex")
    public void logException(MyOwnException ex) {
      System.out.println("MyOwnException has been thrown: " + ex.getMessage());
      ex.addSuppressed(alreadyAdviced);
    }
}
```

`AspectTwo` with modified `Order` and logic to check for already adviced.

```java
@Component
@Aspect
@Order(0)
public class AspectTwo {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.test.MyService.*(..))")
    public void logException() {
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "logException()", throwing = "ex")
    public void logException(RuntimeException ex) {
        if (isAlreadyAdviced(ex)) {
            System.out.println("Already Adviced : Skipping");
        } else {
            System.out.println("RuntimeException has been thrown: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private boolean isAlreadyAdviced(RuntimeException ex) {
        for(Throwable e : ex.getSuppressed()) {
            if(AspectOne.ALREADY_ADVICED_MSG.equals(e.getMessage())){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```